# Shouldn't `typename` only be used in template function or template class?

Tags: c++, typename

Shouldn't `typename` only be used in template function or template class? Why the expresion below is legal?What's the function of typename in the expresion below?

```
#define DECLARE(T)  using Request = typename T::Request;
```

I would be grateful for any hint on this question.

Comment: *"the expresion below"* - it is a macro, not an expression

Comment: I would follow your advice to modify it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename

Comment: It's for [dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  Sorry, I have read the documentation aforementioned,  but i still could not get the idea.

Comment: @churill I would see it right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to allow using such expression in a macro (like mentioned in the original post).

Macro cannot know if it is used with template type argument or not, but has to work in both. Since `typename` is required when working with a template, it makes sense to allow it in non-template code (where it can be ignored).

Your original code serves as the example of such usage (`;` at the end removed):

```
#define DECLARE(T)   using Request = typename T::Request
```

This macro work in both template and non-template code:

```
struct Container { using Request = int; };
struct A { DECLARE(Container); };
template<typename T>
struct B { DECLARE(T); };
```

Without `typename`, you would get compilation error for such code:

```
B<Container>();
```

Comment: Thank you.You are right.I thought over and over and tried on the online compiler(https://godbolt.org/z/XNBLik). I got this error indeed(`need 'typename' before 'T::REQUEST' because 'T' is a dependent scope`) while compiled without the `typename` .What does this error implie?What is "dependent scope"?

Comment: @John You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/1143634) answer. It has a quote from the standard that gives the definition of it. Look for the "If a name has this property - that it can't be looked up until the actual template arguments are known - then it's called a dependent name". Then check quote from (14.6/2) there.

Comment: It's so kind of you.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That your line is a macro, which is a directive to preprocessor to replace all the occurances of `DECLARE(T)` with `using Request = typename T::Request;`, at the same time replacing the type `T` with the supplied real-type. For example, if the compiler sees anywhere `DECLARE(string)`, it will replace that with `using Request = typename string::Request;`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.I could guess the result.But  what's the function of  `typename` in `#define DECLARE(T) using Request = typename T::Request;`?

Comment: The keyword ```using``` and ```typename``` here are used for aliases alongside templates. You can read more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias